# Savon SSL Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, savon, httpi

I'm struggling to get the Savon gem to connect to one of our servers.  I keep getting an error stating I can't get past the ssl.  I've read numerous tutorials and fixes but none seem to work.

Any help appreciated - this will make my Monday if I can get past it :-).

Error:

```
D, [2011-06-20T09:43:02.002993 #10328] DEBUG -- : Retrieving WSDL from: http://path_to_wsdl:4443/sm/services/mailing/2009/03/02?wsdl
D, [2011-06-20T09:43:02.129057 #10328] DEBUG -- : HTTPI executes HTTP GET using the httpclient adapter
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:276:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert unexpected message (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

My code:

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new "path_to_my_wsdl"

client.http.auth.ssl.cert_file = "path/cert.pem"

client.http.auth.ssl.cert_key_file = "/path/localhost.key"
client.http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none

client.wsse.credentials "username", "password"

client.wsdl.soap_actions
```

Comment: Are you certain SSL is running on port 4433?

Comment: As far as I know - when I access the wsdl file its under https - if I do it via browser it flags it as a self signed certificate.  I'm wondering why/how the verify_mode = :none isn't kicking in.

Comment: which version of the httpi gem are you using?

Comment: Was running httpi (0.9.3) but now updated to 0.9.4.  Same output though. :-(

Comment: not sure if that's the problem, but it seems that if verify_mode is set to :none, [both cert and key are not set](https://github.com/rubiii/httpi/blob/v0.9.4/lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb#L84)?! you could try to remove the unless statement.

Comment: Yeah - I may have this butchered... Problem is I don't know what settings are required:

request.auth.ssl.cert_key_file     = "client_key.pem"
request.auth.ssl.cert_file         = "client_cert.pem"
request.auth.ssl.ca_cert_file      = "ca_cert.pem"  

On my other API calls, that I don't use httpi on, I simply set ":ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE" which works fine.

Here though some sort of cert is required and I don't quite know how to determine which one.

Comment: I'm curious if there's any way of just skipping the SSL?  Quite frankly I'm wondering if I'm referencing the wrong cert/key.  To avoid this would be easiest to skip over the SSL.

Comment: Trying this to get SSL to work over HTTPI:

https://gist.github.com/0de6e2b3c5027699a211

Comment: Update - SSL works fine on authenticated ssl - the issue I'm having is on self-signed ssl - which leads me to think that the code is fine - its the server I'm connecting to that has the issues.  Never-the-less trying to find a workaround.

Comment: if you can provide access to the service and the ssl certificate, i'll make sure to get this working. please get in touch via (me at rubiii dot com). i don't think so comments are the best way to discuss this.

Comment: if it's working fine with a self-signed certificate using httpclient on its own, then it should work through httpi. if it doesn't and the self-signed certificate seems to be the problem, then i don't know if i can help.

Comment: Rubii - you've been great help and are kind.  I don't think its your code.  I think this is a server/host issue.  I've been connecting to just about every other server on the planet - but this one in particular.  Very strange.  I'm going to contact the owner to see what's up.  Otherwise I may take you up on your offer.  Kind Regard - Adam O

Comment: thanks for the help - ended up being a host issue on the target box :-). Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Savon 2.x support ssl global option:

```
Savon.client(ssl_verify_mode: :none)
```

and

```
Savon.client(ssl_version: :SSLv3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you did this already, but when I had to use Savon for a project I found it incredibly useful to make sure the Soap server was working as I thought it should with SoapUI (http://www.eviware.com/). You can then output the SOAP request from the two and compare..

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2232850) in Ruby's net/http handling of the SSL handshake.

Try forcing the SSL version to get around the bug:

```
client.http.auth.ssl.sock.ssl_version="SSLv3"
```